# Changing Shape of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

**This is how my data displays in jupyter**
[image]

**I want is to display this way with month coverted to datetime and employed canadians to float or integer**
[image]

I used this code but I keep getting errors "Not define for months and employed canadians"

```
nfl2 = nfl.melt(id_vars=["Month", "Employer Persons"], 
    var_name="Province", 
    value_name="Newfoundland and Labrador")


nfl2 = nfl2.rename(columns={'Province': 'Months','Newfoundland and Labrador': 'Employed Canadians'})

nfl_final['Months'] = nfl_final['Months'].dt.strftime('%y-%m' )
nfl_final = nfl_final['Employer Persons'] = pd.Series(dtype='int')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Province': 'Newfound and Labrador',
    'January': 204,
    'February': 204,
    'March': 195,
    'April': 173,
    'May': 179,
    'June': 197,
    'July': 204
}

nfl = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
nfl = nfl.transpose().drop('Province').reset_index()
nfl = nfl.rename({'index': 'Months', 0: 'Employed Canadians'}, axis=1)
nfl['Employed Canadians'] = nfl['Employed Canadians'].astype(float)
nfl['Months'] = pd.to_datetime(nfl['Months'], format='%B')
nfl['Months'] = nfl['Months'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=2020))
```

This should work.

Note that because you haven't provided a year or day for each of these dates, the datetime object defaults to 1970-01-01, I've changed it to 2020 using the lambda function in the end. You can easily format these datetimes to be presented as month names only but that will change the datatype to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You used `melt` wrongly. I recommend you to review the documentation / tutorials to see how it works.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Province":["Hee"], "January":[4.12], "February":[76.23423]}).set_index("Province")

nfl2 = df.melt(value_vars=["January", "February"], var_name=["Months"], value_name="Employed")
nfl2.index = range(1,3)
nfl2['Months'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(nfl2['Months'], format='%B')).month
nfl2
```

Results:

```
    Months  Employed
1   1   4.12000
2   2   76.23423
```

I allowed myself to create a small example with only two months. You can expand it as you wish. Please provide a code to preproduce your dataframe next time you ask a question.

When using the `melt`, you should declare your months as the "value_vars" (since they are values). The index shift was made to start indexing from 1 instead of 0.

You weren't very specific about which datetime format exactly do you want, so I took only months. `%B` translates from "January" to a date format, and then I extract only the month